# How to add xmlrpc lib to java library

Tags: java

Hello
I want to add xmlrpc lib to java libraries in linux.
I add this library to eclipse project but i can't use code complition option in eclise how can i use this feature in eclipse with xmlRpc library?
please help me

Comment: adding project build path xmlrpc should work for you

Comment: how can i add project build path xmlrpc

Comment: I want to use eclipse code complition with xmlRpc objects

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Comment: I do this with method2 but eclipse can't open java doc for this jars because xmlrpc jars apidoc folder aren't in jar file in other words apidoc folder is in xmlrpc main folder and aren't in jar files. so that eclipse code complition don't work for xmlrpc jars

Comment: Are you trying to get code "COMPLETION" in eclipse for that? You need to add the source for the xmlrpc libraries to eclipse in order to get the popups in eclipse when using the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the library from this site

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/ws/xmlrpc/

and then like someone said earlier 
Properties --> Build Path --> Libraries --> Add External JARs --> (then add it in)

Answer (score 0):

To get code completion for a library packaged in a jar, you need to tell Eclipse where the code (or the javadoc) for the project resides.

The easiest way is to open the build path of your project, then right-click on the .jar. The context-menu offers to attach the source or the javadoc location for the .jar.

Comment: I can't find xmlRpc source but i find xmlrpc docs and add them to eclipse where you said how can i find source of xmlrpc for java and add it to my eclipse project?

Comment: @taher: Depends on the xmlrpc library you use. Look at its download page, maybe it's provided there.

Comment: thanks i download xmlrpc from this site can you see source of xmlrpc in it http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/download.html if you see tell me to download it very thanks

Comment: I don't know which folder i should choose in xmlRpc source folder it has many folders!